# merge list of lists into one by averaging each value in lists r

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

So I'm not really sure about the best way to achieve what I want to do.

Here is my **problem**: I'm using multiple imputation in R with the package mice and I'm using the function cox.zph to get the residuals for each imputed model. I would like to average all the imputed residuals to get only one value for each variable. And honestly I have no idea how to achieve this. I've looked at lapply and mapply.

```
res.scho <- NULL
for (i in 1:m) {
    res.scho[[i]] <- cox.zph(modf$analyses[[i]])
}

res.scho[[1]]
              rho  chisq        p
Alc=1       0.0622  0.552 4.58e-01
HIV=1       0.1050  1.873 1.71e-01
Diabetes=1 -0.1240  2.227 1.36e-01
age        -0.1388  2.877 8.99e-02
GLOBAL          NA 44.467 5.97e-08
```

Basically I have m imputed dataset and res.scho[[m]] and I would like to combine each res.scho into one.

I'm still very stuck at forloops that I used in other languages and I'm having some problems to use mapply. This could be one of the issue. Nevertheless, I would be really grateful if someone could give me some pointers to help me achieve this and better use R.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

EXpected output:

Let's say I have two imputed datasets. m=2

```
res.scho[[1]]
              rho  chisq        p
Alc=1       0.0622  0.552 4.58e-01
HIV=1       0.1050  1.873 1.71e-01
Diabetes=1 -0.1240  2.227 1.36e-01
age        -0.1388  2.877 8.99e-02
GLOBAL          NA 44.467 5.97e-08

res.scho[[2]]
              rho  chisq        p
Alc=1       0.0522  0.752 5.58e-01
HIV=1       0.1550  1.473 2.71e-01
Diabetes=1 -0.1140  2.927 4.36e-01
age        -0.1188  2.077 3.99e-02
GLOBAL          NA 44.400 7.97e-08
```

My desired output would be in the same form as the list but the average of the two for each value, for instance:

```
 Average_res.scho
              rho  chisq        p
Alc=1       0.0572  0.652 5.08e-01
HIV=1       0.1300  1.673 2.21e-01
Diabetes=1 -0.1190  2.577 2.86e-01
age        -0.1288  2.477 4.24e-02
GLOBAL          NA 44.433 6.97e-08
```

for instance the column of rho is obtained by colum (res.scho[[1]] + res.scho[[2]]) /2

**EDIT1**

Following the suggestions of konvas I'm trying to use his ideas to get the desired output. Here is what I have so far:

```
rho <- NULL
chisq <- NULL
p <- NULL
for (i in 1:70) {
    rho[[i]] <- res.scho[[i]]$table[,"rho"]
    chisq[[i]] <- res.scho[[i]]$table[,"chisq"]
    p[[i]] <- res.scho[[i]]$table[,"p"]
```

I've extracted a list of lists for each column of res.scho - not the perfect solution. So if I do rho[[1]] I see the first column

```
 [[1]]
  CliForm=1       Sit=2       Alc=1       HIV=1  Diabetes=1         age      GLOBAL 
  0.17300198 -0.45800541  0.06224951  0.10495093 -0.12401631 -0.13879592          NA
```

Now, I will thinking about to this for rho, chisq and p:

```
for (i in 1:70) {
    result <- sapply(names(rho[[1]]),
             function(x) colMeans(sapply(rho, "[[", x)))
}
```

And I get the following error that I've been trying to solve:

```
 Error in colMeans(sapply(rho, "[[", x)) :   'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Comment: `cox.zph` is just a test of significance for your parameters. There are no residuals associated with that test, the residuals for the fitted vs predicted values are associated with the model fit that you pass to the test. The residuals are likely in the `modf$analysis` list. You can likely extract them with `resid(modf$analysis[[i]])`. If you are talking about residuals of the test statistics you will have to define what you mean by that. I don't understand how you want to combine these results.

Comment: thank you for your comment @MrFlick. You're right I should have been more clear. The cox.zph tests the Proportional Hazards Assumption of a Cox Regression and I want the combine the m outputs into one. The point is that it doesn't really matter if I'm talking about residuals or the test because the idea is how to average all of them to provide only one list. I will provide an expected output. Hope this will let everything more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, extract the relevant matrix of coefficients for each entry of the list `res.scho`:

```
res.scho.tables <- lapply(res.scho, `[[`, "table")
```

Then since all you want is an average (and matrices can be added up elementwise quite fast) you can call

```
Average_res.scho <- do.call(`+`, res.scho.tables) / length(res.scho.tables)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your reply. Your solution does not work for the data since the output of res.scho is a bit more trickier than I was expecting. Neverthelees, I've tried to play a bit around with it (still not figured out how to give the nice output your provided). I will update the answer with an attempt to reproduce your code

Comment: @pavid Hey, I read your edit and perhaps the way I wrote the answer was not 100% clear. The stuff I wrote in the beginning was just an explanation of what the code does, not extra code that you needed to write. The code to do what you want is simply `result <- sapply(names(res.scho[[1]]), function(x) rowMeans(sapply(res.scho, "[[", x)))`

Comment: So perhaps I wasn't clear because the code don't work. One of the thing that I haven't noticed is that the names "rho", etc are only acessible through res.scho[[i]]$table so names(res.scho[[1]]) returns NULL and therefore sapply(res.scho, "[[", x) will not work. Nevertheless, if I'm not mistaken I would need a loop since names(res.scho[[1]]) only works for res.scho[[1]] and will not produce the mean for the 70 lists inside res.scho. Do you understand what I trying to say? Hope I correctly explained the problem

Comment: I think I kind of understand although I cannot reproduce it. The names(res.scho[[1]]) is only used to loop through the names of each table (the index 1 is chosen arbitrarily, it could be anything else, since they all contain the same columns). Now, in order to get rid of having to call "$table" all the time, does it work if you first do `res.scho <- lapply(res.scho, "[[", "table")` and then call `result <- sapply(names(res.scho[[1]]), function(x) rowMeans(sapply(res.scho, "[[", x)))`?

Comment: No, it does not work. I'm only able to get the colnames doing this: colnames(res.scho[[1]]$table) [1] "rho"   "chisq" "p" the problem is that like this, your function does not work. That was why I was playing around (without success).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the output of `dput(res.scho)` where `res.scho` is the example list (of length 2) in your post in the first edit? Then I can try to reproduce the example and check what is the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! And thank you for the suggestion to use dput. I didn't know this function! but the output is huge! even for two iterations. You can check the dput(res.scho) here: http://pastie.org/9298898

Comment: OK, so the problem here is that I am not familiar with the package you are using and I needed to fiddle around with it. I don't know if the following solution is optimal but it worked when I tried it (please check the output carefully to make sure it does what you want). First, use `res.scho.tables <- lapply(res.scho, "[[", "table")` in order to extract the relevant matrix for each entry. Then since all you want is an average (and matrices can be added up elementwise quite fast) you can call `Average_res.scho <- do.call("+", res.scho.tables) / length(res.scho)`.

Comment: Yes, this will work! Thank you! The output is quite nasty but it stores more information. Thank you very much for all your time!